# Name of Attached file uploaded via form saved to csv file

Tags: php

Hi I have the code to save all submissions via a web form to save to a csv file. The only problem I'm having is the files that get uploaded with the enquiry. As it's not writing the file name.

Here is my code...

```
<?PHP 
class MySaveToCsv extends FM_ExtensionModule
{
function BeforeStartProcessing()
{
$customername = $_POST['CustomerName'];
$companyname = $_POST['CompanyName'];
$noemps = $_POST['NoEmps'];
$telephone = $_POST['TelephoneNo'];
$email = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
$addressline1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
$addressline2 = $_POST['AddressLine2'];
$addressline3 = $_POST['AddressLine3'];
$city = $_POST['City'];
$county = $_POST['County'];
$postcode = $_POST['PostCode'];
$enquiry = $_POST['Enquiry'];
$file = $_POST['upload'];
$source = $_POST['Source'];
$quotecode = $_POST['QuoteCode'];

if(count($_FILES)){
        $form_image_path = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/forms/";
            switch($this->enquiryType){
                case "ContactUs" :
                $form_image_path .= "WebEnquiry/formdata/t_uploads_ContactUs/";

        }
        $i = 1;
        foreach($_FILES as $file){
            $dummy .= "Image Attachment No. " . $i . " : " . $file['name'] . "\r\n";
            $i++;
        }
    }


$fp = fopen('ContactUs.csv', a); 
if($customername){
$savestring = $customername . "|" . $companyname . "|" . $noemps . "|" . $telephone . "|" . $email . "|" . $addressline1 . "|" . $addressline2 . "|" . $addressline3 . "|" . $city . "|" . $county . "|" . $postcode . "|" . $enquiry . "|" . $dummy . "|" . $source . "|" . $quotecode . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);}
fclose($fp);
}
}
?>
```

Second submission after changing some code but problem still exists

```
<?PHP 
class MySaveToCsv extends FM_ExtensionModule
{
function BeforeStartProcessing()
{
$customername = $_POST['CustomerName'];
$companyname = $_POST['CompanyName'];
$noemps = $_POST['NoEmps'];
$telephone = $_POST['TelephoneNo'];
$email = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
$addressline1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
$addressline2 = $_POST['AddressLine2'];
$addressline3 = $_POST['AddressLine3'];
$city = $_POST['City'];
$county = $_POST['County'];
$postcode = $_POST['PostCode'];
$enquiry = $_POST['Enquiry'];
$source = $_POST['Source'];
$quotecode = $_POST['QuoteCode'];
$file = $_POST['upload'];


if(count($_FILES)){

$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/forms/ContactUs/formdata/uploads_ContactUs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

$file_ary = array();
$file_count = count($file_post['name']);
$file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
    foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
        $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
    }
}


return $file_ary;
}
if ($_FILES['upload']) {
$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['ufile']);

foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
    $dummy .= 'File Name: ' . $file['name'];


   }

}


$fp = fopen('ContactUs.csv', a); 
if($customername){
    $today = date("j/m/Y H:i");
$savestring = $today . "|" . $customername . "|" . $companyname . "|" . $noemps . "|" . $telephone . "|" . $email . "|" . $addressline1 . "|" . $addressline2 . "|" . $addressline3 . "|" . $city . "|" . $county . "|" . $postcode . "|" . $enquiry . "|" . $dummy . "|" . $source . "|" . $quotecode . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);}
fclose($fp);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in that script that could go wrong. Either you have the wrong file path, or PHP doesn't have permission to save the file, or `$this->enquiryType` is not set, or your code is not executing as it should.

Try something simpler to make sure you can write the file:

```
$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/WebEnquiry/formdata/t_uploads_ContactUs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

if (file_exists($filepath)) die($_FILES["file"]["name"] . ' - This file already exists.');
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)){
    //Successful. Maybe set a flag.
}
else die('File upload/save error.');
```

Comment out the existing upload code for that, which simply tries to save the uploaded file into the directory you have in your script. PHP Needs write permissions on that directory.

Comment: Hi degenerate, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Firstly the path to the file is correct, secondly the files are being saved to that location by the form. All i need is to add the name of the file uploaded to a cell in the csv file (there could be 2 files added by the form).

Comment: If it helps this is the output i'm getting in the csv file...Bob No-Hope|Great company|46|441243871444|bob@greatcompany.com|Unit 7 Hope Park|Hope Rd||Bognor Regis|Sussex|PO22 5HP|This is a test message|Image Attachment No. 1 : 
|Google|CODE1

Comment: The name of the uploaded file is `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` -- you can write that data to the file after you save it.

Comment: Ok this is what I have so far.. Again it's outputting everything except the file name... 'code'if(count($_FILES)){
   $form_image_path = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/forms/";
   switch($this->enquiryType){
    case "ContactUs" :
     $form_image_path .= "ContactUs/formdata/t_uploads_ContactUs/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]; ;
    
     break;
   }
   $i = 1;
   foreach($_FILES as $file){
    $dummy .= "Image Attachment No. " . $i . " : " . $file['name'] . "\r\n";
    $i++;
   }

Comment: You are assuming that multiple files uploaded can be accessed by iterating through `$_FILES`. This is not true. Please see the PHP manual (and especially the first comment) to see why you cannot simply do `foreach` on the `$_FILES` variable. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240